# Roll up categorical values into second variable Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have data that comes from a data source with pre-coded categorical variables. Unfortunately, these are not the variables that I need for my analysis and need to roll them up into a second column:

```
age_group  lifestage
18-24      young adult
25-34      adult
35-44      adult
45-54      adult
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

I currently am using a loop through lists in order to do this:

```
ya_list = ['18-24']
adult_list = ['25-34', '35-44', '45-54']

for age in age_group:
    if age in ya_list:
        lifestage = 'young adult' 
    elif age in adult_list:
        lifestage = 'adult'
```

This works ok for this example with only a few groups to recode into, but when I have groups with 10 or more groups to recode, it becomes a lot more unwieldy. I can't help but think there has to be a better way to do this, but I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a dictionary:

```
stages = {'18-24': 'young adult',
          '25-34': 'adult', ...}

for age in age_group:
    lifestage = stages[age]
```

This is the canonical replacement for a lot of `elif`s in Python.

Comment: I actually would want to have the key-value pairs flipped from what you have here, which puts me into a one-to-many relationship between the keys and their values: 

    `stages = {'young adult':'18-24', adult:'25-34', adult:'35-44', ...}`
Is this really the best way to do this?

Comment: @Rachel I don't follow, that's the same way I have them; you're going from age group (key) to life stage (value). I don't know about "best", but it's fast (key lookup is `O(1)` in Python dicts) and saves you from line after line of `elif`.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my comment; I had copy-pasted from your response and forgot to reverse the values.

Comment: @Rachel that seems to be the opposite of what the code in your question is doing. It won't work the other way; dictionary keys must be unique, this is part of what enables the fast lookups.

Comment: I think I had too much sql on the brain to get this before. Went over it with a clear head and it worked perfectly. Thank you, and apologies. :)

Comment: @Rachel not a problem, glad the confusion has cleared!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()` and a list comprehension to get the actual numbers to work with:

```
for age in age_group:
    lower,higher = [int(i) for i in age.split("-")]
    if higher <= 24:
        lifestage = "young adult"
    elif lower <= 54:
        lifestage = "adult"
    # etc...
```

Not sure if what you are scaling up is the number of age ranges, or the number of stages, but hopefully that will help you get started.

Comment: I don't have access to the raw numbers, just the ranges, unfortunately.

Comment: Right, what my code is doing is splitting the ranges into two strings by the dash. `"25-34".split("-")` returns `["25","34"]`. Then using `int()` returns the actual numbers.

Comment: Huh. Clever.
Sadly, I also have some other variables that are not integer-based, so this won't work for those cases.